# Is empty struct defined by C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any `std::empty` struct or something similar or do I need to define my own:

```
struct empty{};
```

This can be used very nice in combination with `std::conditional` or other new std features and I wonder if the standard defines it or not.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, no.

Comment: Do you want a struct which just have no data members (thus have a size of 1), or a truly empty struct?

Comment: Perhaps `std::tuple<>`?

Comment: @KennyTM I don't think it's possible to have truly empty struct and be able to declare variables of that type. I think classes derived from empty struct will optimize it's size and it should behave like "0 size" struct in this case

Comment: @Felics: No you can declare variables of an empty struct http://ideone.com/wCfWXu. Deriving an empty struct does make it behave like 0 size though (that's the technique used by `boost::compressed_pair`).

Comment: @KennyTM I don't think this is correct... Because if you declare 2 variable of the empty type the must have different addresses. If the size is 0 they will have same address

Comment: What are you trying to do? It may be `typedef` and traits will serve the purpose adequately.

Comment: @Felics: Are we talking about the same thing? By deriving I mean `struct Derived : Empty { }` won't increase the size of `Derived`. But an empty derived class  must still have a size of 1.

Comment: [`boost::blank`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/blank.hpp) exists, but afaik, there's no empty struct exposed in the `std` namespace

Comment: Does the requirement that different objects have different addresses actually __really__ require that an empty struct has a size greater than zero? I think this is only a "compiler convenience". In principle, a compiler could give empty objects a "random" address (that does not alias something else). Since the object is "emtpy", you cannot dereference it in a meaningful way, so any valid or invalid address is as good as any other (... as long as it doesn't alias).

Comment: @Damon: In which case, the empty object would occupy the unique address that it's given, taking up one byte of address space, wherever you put it. Which is equivalent to saying it has a size of (at least) one byte. (And of course, the compiler can only assign addresses to objects with static storage duration; others get their addresses at runtime).

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Would it, really? You cannot read the address nor write to it (since the object is "empty"). There is nothing you can do but compare its address against the null pointer or another object's address. So, it would be perfectly legitimate to give it an address in the .text segment - it wouldn't "occupy" anything, at least not anything that is not occupied already anyway. Or, it would be legitimate to assign an address that is not addressable by the hardware, such as on typical 64bit processors that can only address 48 or 52 bits. Or, e.g. the address `(char*)&other_int_variable+1`.

Comment: @Damon: As I said, it would occupy a byte of address space, since its address must be unique. From that point of view, it's size is (at least) one byte. I guess the point you're making is that it could in principle be placed in part of the address space that isn't mapped to real memory (assuming a virtual memory architecture); in which case, you're correct that it wouldn't occupy any real memory. But that would be quite an expensive optimisation (probably requiring a second "stack" for automatic objects, and special handling for dynamic ones), and I've never heard of any compiler doing that.

Comment: @Damon: Although, having reread your comments, I assume you're only suggesting this as an optimisation for static objects.

Comment: @Damon : all elements of an array are required by the standard to have distinct and consecutive addresses (`&array[i+1] == &array[i] + 1` if `i` is between `0` and `n-1` where `n` is number of elements) for all types - that is necessary for pointer arithmetic to work.  `sizeof` for the array is also required to yield an `unsigned` value with value `n*sizeof element`.   That set of requirements could not all be met if `sizeof` yielded a value of zero for any type .... including for an empty struct.

Comment: @Peter: Yes, that is perfectly correct, and it sure must be the case for every type, for that exact reason. Only just... it's that array access or pointer arithmetic working properly is totally irrelevant for an "empty". An array of empties is an array of things you cannot do anything with. As is the size of the array. I'm with Joseph von Sonnleithner (the writer of the libretto to _Fidelio_) on that one: _"If nothing comes to nothing, the resulting sum is, and stays small"_. If an object is empty/invalid/inaccessible, then every other emtpy/invalid object is indstinguishable from that one.

Comment: Insofar, I think one _could_ argue that using the same address for different objects is legitimate per the "as if" rule. Since either way, the object is invalid at one address, or at the other address, you cannot make out any difference between them. They are both "the" invalid object, there is exactly one unusable object, or there are infinitely many... but it makes no observable difference.

Comment: Simple boolean expressions like `&a == &b` or `&a != &b`, where `a` and `b` are distinct instances of an empty struct, would be able to detect the difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is a section to add this kind of construct as part of the [Variant proposal (n4542)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4542.pdf).

After being voted on,

> What do we want to call the “empty_t” stand-in type?
> empty_t 4
> empty 4
> one_t 1
> blank 6
> blank_t 7
> monostate 7
>
> Runoff:
> blank* 3
> monostate 8

the agreed upon name would be:  std::monostate.

---

It would be defined the following way:

```
// 2.?, Explicitly default-constructed alternative
struct monostate {};
bool operator<(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return false; }
bool operator>(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return false; }
bool operator<=(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return true; }
bool operator>=(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return true; }
bool operator==(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return true; }
bool operator!=(const monostate&, const monostate&) constexpr
{ return false; }
```

Answer (score 8):

It is defined as [std::monostate](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) in header [<variant>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/variant)

```
struct monostate { };
```

It is used for example in `std::variant` ( a type-safe union ), where `std::variant<std::monostate>` represents an empty variant. Monostate makes variants default-constructible.

Answer (score 6):

EDIT: with the introduction of [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) in C++17 this answer is outdated. See other answers for more information.

There is no such a thing in the c++ standard library. As mentioned in the comments, you can still find [`boost::blank`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/boost/blank.hpp) in Boost which is probably what resembles the most to the class you are looking for. If such a class existed in the standard library, I don't think there would be so many third-party libraries defining their own `struct empty {}`.

If what you want is just a class with no data members and the smallest possible size - cannot be smaller than 1 - (and possibly benefit from the empty base optimization), you can still use `std::tuple<>`. It is actually used for that exact purpose (empty base optimization) in the implementation of some classes in the libstdc++.

If you want to make sure `std::tuple<>` really is an empty class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    // prints 1
    std::cout << std::is_empty< std::tuple<> >::value;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for an error return type for using with `std::conditional`. Usually people define their own empty struct types for metaprogramming. This makes sense as it is usually not possible to design metaprogramming libraries in a way that they can easily interact with arbitrary other compile-time libraries.

The closest thing to a de-facto standard is probably [Boost.MPL](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/index.html), so using something like [mpl::void_](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/mpl/doc/refmanual/void.html) might make sense in your situation.

If you insist on sticking to Standard types, `nullptr_t` seems to be a good match.

Comment: Using `nullptr_t` for this is actually quite a nice idea.

Comment: The only problem of `nullptr_t` is that, if instanciated, it is required to be as least a large as a `void*` instance. This shouldn't be a problem if the only use is metaprogramming.