# What can I use as a NULL struct?

Tags: c++, interface, struct, null

I'd like to code a loop going through several instances of the same struct (named edg in my case) iterated by a certain function going from neighbor to neighbor until it returns an element that says STOP. I tried coding it using a NULL return but it doesn't work. What could I use?

Here is some code explaining it probably more accurately than my previous words:
My structure:

```
struct edg{
int i,j,k;
edg(int a, int b, int c){
i = a; j = b; k = c; //I'm adding a constructor to it
}
}
```

My iterating function:

```
edg neighbour(edg temp){
if(temp satisfies certain criterias){ return edg(new coordinates);}
else{ return NULL;}
}
```

My loop:

```
while(my_edg!=NULL){
my_edg = neighbour(my_edg);
}
```

I guess I could just pick a certain value of an edg define it as a rejection, and replace in my loop by:

```
while(my_edg!=edg_marked_as_rejection)
```

But is there another way to do so?

Comment: There's `boost::optional`.

Comment: "I tried coding it using a NULL return but it doesn't work." - for NULL to work(compile!), you have to return a pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is empty struct defined by C++ standard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16666871/is-empty-struct-defined-by-c-standard)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that your function:

```
edg neighbour(edg temp){
    if(temp satisfies certain criterias){ return edg(new coordinates); }
    else{ return NULL; }
}
```

returns an instance of `edg` by value thus trying to `return NULL;` is invalid (unless you've defined some custom conversion). `NULL` is a possible value when passing / returning by pointer, which in this case could mean changing the prototype of this function to:

```
edg* neighbour(edg temp) { ... }
```

however based on the semantics it would be more reasonable to either pass by reference and return a flag indicating success:

```
bool neighbour(const edg& temp, edg& result) {
    if (...) {
        result = ...;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

or in case your condition *"`if(temp satisfies certain criterias)`"* should be met in most of cases and these criteria not being met is rather an exceptional state, you might also consider throwing an exception (instead of returning `NULL`).

A third option might be implementing a *NULL object design pattern*, meaning that instance of `edg` marked as "invalid" would be constructed and returned and caller would do something like:

```
edg n = neighbour(tmp);
if (!n.isValid()) {
    ...
}
```