# Does an empty structure have a meaning?

Tags: c++, struct

I have a block of code like this:

```
struct CommErr {};

class C {
   virtual void Func(int i, const int *ptr, CommErr);
};

...
C c;
c.Func(i, p, {});
```

`CommErr` is not a base class/structure.

What can be the purpose of an empty `CommErr` structure?

Comment: seems a dupe of [Usage of empty structs in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60685261/usage-of-empty-structs-in-c) or probably others discoverable by searching ;-) *[flagged with a worse dupe at first; d'oh]*

Comment: needs more context. My first idea would be to disambiuate different overloads that have identical signature otherwise by adding different "dummy" parameters, but there is only one `Str` and only one overload.

Comment: You can use it to force an overload to be chosen over a different one. I believe have seen this idea with boost::MultiIndex they call it tags

Comment: C++17 already provides a convenient empty struct for you, [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate).  Another use of an empty struct is just for type tagging, like a public constructor that takes a private key (because `std::make_unique` needs the constructor to be public).